# Why is Egypt not able to stop the building of a dam in Ethiopia?

Tags: africa, egypt, ethiopia

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF841nm_7RQ). This video portrays Egypt as a victim of the dam built by Ethiopia.

Egypt is a regional power with arguably the strongest military in Africa. It is also well-connected to the international community.

Why is Egypt not able to stop the building of a dam in Ethiopia, Or, at least make Ethiopia come to favorable terms with it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://qz.com/africa/1862962/ethiopia-egypt-battle-for-river-nile-grand-dam-without-trump/), it would seem that Egypt implicitly recognizes Ethiopia has a legitimate right to build a dam, and that both Egypt and Ethiopia want an international agreement, including Sudan, about the details. Egypt has invited the United States to moderate but it doesn't seem to be very interested in playing an active role in this. An agreement may still be reached but there are real disagreements that will need to be resolved. In sum, I would say that negotiations are ongoing and Egypt has so far been unsuccessful in getting international support to impose a favorable agreement on Ethiopia.

Comment: Why is Egypt not trying to play foul? I mean, why just not bomb the dam?

Comment: That would be an act of war, which no country would take lightly. There are major international disputes all the time that do not provoke such attacks.

Comment: And considering that [dams are specifically protected by the Geneva conventions](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docs/v2_cha_chapter13_rule42), this might not just be interpreted as an unprovoked act of war but even an unprovoked warcrime.

Comment: An unprovoked act of war is a war crime per se. But I understand your point.